# how to get data from rfid reader with ttl gpio in ARM?

Tags: linux, serial-port, gpio, rfid, ttl

I have a [NanoPc-T2](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPC-T2). I want to connect RFID reader ([EM-18](http://www.nskelectronics.com/em-18_rfid_reader.html)) to UART gpio pin (pin number 4 is RX).  I make this gpio 112 for `UART2_RX/GPIOD16`

```
root@NanoPC-T2:/sys/class/gpio# for i in gpiochip* ; do echo `cat $i/label`: `cat $i/base` ; done
GPIOA: 0
GPIOE: 128
GPIOALV: 160
GPIOB: 32
GPIOC: 64
GPIOD: 96
root@NanoPC-T2:/sys/class/gpio# echo 112 > export    /////112=96+16 (GPIOD: 96 + GPIOD 16)
```

I connect vcc to 5 volt vcc, and gnd to gnd, and tx rfid reader to RX nanopc-t2.
How can I set baudrate to 9600 and other option, and read card data from linux console?

Comment: *"UART gpio pin"* -- You seem confused.  A pin can be multiplexed to be used by a peripheral (e.g. by the UART as the RxD pin), OR for general purpose I/O (aka GPIO).  A pin cannot be used simultaneously for both a UART and GPIO, and even runtime/dynamic multiplexing is discouraged even if the board could support it.  For modern Linux ARM kernels, the proper method of assigning pins to a peripheral (e.g. the UART) is using the Device Tree.  You *cannot* perform this pin assignment through **sysfs**.

Comment: yes you say right, I find out that when I use pin as UART so should use this dev: /dev/ttyAMA* for UART pin

Comment: *"so should use this dev: /dev/ttyAMA* for UART pin"* -- I can't tell if you're making a statement or asking a question.  Inspect the Linux boot log for the installed serial terminal devices, e.g. `dmesg | grep tty`.  BTW you need to clarify if you have the bare EM-18 module (with TTL interface) or the board (with RS-232 interface).

Comment: yes, thank you. I will use `dmesg | grep tty` , Before I used EM-18 and it used ttl.